# Strange Visual Artifacts, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

yesterday I down graded my Nvidia Drivers to the 337.88 version, via downloading the driver setup from the Nvidia Site. Today I installed malwarebytes, and left it do a full scan and I was aware from the PC for around 2 hours.

I come back, and I notice a slight blue tint on chrome, odd discolouring on explorer windows and on my Steam Client, jagged blueish lines. Bewildered, I just shutdown steam, and slightly tugged the DVI twisty knobs (sorry if thats the wrong word) and I noticed everything seemed to be normal

here is an example of the dicolouring of explorer:

[image]

Wait, what artifacts? Yes, I can't see them either, however I am 100% sure when I created the file (prtscr) and put it into the paint, the artifacts were there, so I can probably confirm there is some hardware stuff going on here. Chrome isn't tinted either in this photo.

Note in the above image, that was the second time it happened. Same deal, I ran the full scan of malwarebytes with steam running, I come back, I closed steam (however I didn't tug any wires) and then it just went back to normal.

Now, here is a photo I took with my tablet, showing strange artifacts on steam.

[image]

What is the problem here? Is it most likely old drivers or is it hardware going? as you can see in the prtscr image, there is no discolouring, so I'm guessing it could have something to do with hardware or drivers.

Comment: Why did you downgrade the drivers? Driver updates often contain fixes for issues like this. Have you tried installing the latest driver update?

Comment: I noticed higher memory usage for some reason with the newer driver, and when I went back it seemed normal. I will try tommorrow with the new drivers.